# Variant of lion and 100 zebras

Tags: mathematics, geometry, strategy, game, pursuit-evasion

*Note:* This problem remains unsolved, as of 19 April 2020, so do try it out. 400 rep bounty guaranteed for a correct answer

---

This a variation of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9036/the-lion-and-the-zebras) by @Gamow

Suppose there are $100$ lions and $100$ zebras. The lions function together as a team (perfect communication and united decision making), and so do the zebras. The lions place themselves first on an infinite plane, and the zebras place themselves next. Game proceeds turn-wise, one turn for the lion team, one for the zebra team. On each turn, a single zebra or lion (depending on which team's turn it is) moves by up to $100$ metres. Team decides which of their members moves, no restrictions on the pick. All positions and movements are public knowledge.

Lions win if a single zebra is eaten. Zebras will try to ensure this doesn't happen. Do the lions' have a strategy that works irrespective of the zebras' one?

P.p.s. Since this question is still attracting poor answers, let me simplify Veedrac's result. If x lions start in a circular formation and move radially outwards, no more than x zebras can forever escape this circle. x lions can always enclose 100-x zebras in their circle, where x is the lion team's choice. The question now becomes how this circle can be tightened without letting the zebras escape.

Comment: If the movements are limited to the grid than any move out of the strip will maintain the distance from the chasing lion. Clearly when the number of lions is small it is easy for zebras to escape. When the number of lions is high the potential strategy would be to get behind one zebra. The advantage of the lions over the zebras could be based on the fact the a single move of a lion may close the range to couple of zebras. The lions strategy will be to use several to chase and the rest to create a trapping line.

Comment: It's weird - this puzzle is a magnetized steel-toothed trap for hasty but wrong answers. Like the last two lion and zebras threads, we already have three failed attempts.

Comment: A lone zebra is surrounded by 100 lions. The lions may choose their initial positions, but must start at least D distance away. The zebra decides D. I believe (but cannot prove) that the zebra can escape.

Comment: @Lopsy But there are 100 zebras, which are harder to protect than a lone one.

Comment: They have infinite time I assume?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code When you say "turn-wise", do you mean that every animal must move exactly once every 200 turns? Otherwise, if you meant 'any lion' - 'any zebra' - 'any lion' ..., then this reduces to the original problem if 99 lions are static and only 1 lion does all the lion-moves.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code On second thought, having multiple lions means you can play / position the lions to cut off certain escape routes, which is qualitatively different from having just 1 lion.

Comment: "Zebras are placed next" I assume that the zebras can adapt their strategy based on the position of the lions?

Comment: @Lawrence There is no restriction on which lion/deer is to be moved, or whether you want to make a move at all.

Comment: @Builder_K Yes, they can, and obviously must.

Comment: I don't understand the question, can the zebras choose where they want to start?

Comment: Can we find any number of zebras, lions for which the lions win?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, I was thinking that infinite time might allow them to play for a draw. :)

Comment: @AE If it remains inconclusive (a draw) even after sufficiently large number of moves, there would probably be some way to prove that the lions cannot win. Either the moves would end up in a cycle, or there would be some general trend towards or away from the goal.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Yes, the zebras select their starting positions after the lions have done so.

Comment: zebras can form a ring enclosing area covered by 100 lions (placed initially) with some safer value of diameter distance.

Comment: Is there a winning condition for zebras?

Comment: @Daniel Not really. The zebras can be said to *win* if they logically prove that they cannot lose.

Comment: At the end of the week, if you don't award the bounty, then the system will automatically award it to the post with the greatest number of votes, correct?

Comment: @JLee What I read, the system awards *half* the bounty to the most voted answer. Veedrac will probably get another 50 rep.

Comment: Does the nature/behaviour of the animals factor into the question ?

Comment: @moonbutt74 No, they are just two kinds of objects (which I have given animal names).

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Do you believe you know the correct answer to this?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No

Comment: The Zebras can place themselves anywhere?

Comment: Happy new year! It's 2019 now! :D (And happy lunar year for 79 minutes from now if you live in Kiritimati!)

Comment: even if the question remains unanswered (and I myself can't answer it as well, because I lack the brains to do so), this site is anything but dying :0

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code When the Zebras are placed, do they get to see the lions' placement?

Comment: @UnidentifiedX Certainly. Game of perfect information

Comment: My friend said it might be an unsolved mystery. Should we tag it?

Comment: @CulverKwan I doubt my question satisfies the "famous" requirement for the tag, but I don't mind if it'll help attract attention.

Comment: @ ghosts in the code. Do you have any reason for not responding to my answer?

Answer (score 21):

I have no idea who can win, but I do want to clear up one point that some other people seem to be overlooking. Namely, the lions can always surround some plurality of zebras so any strategy to keep the zebras on the outside is doomed by construction.

---

Let $n \ge 100$ be the number of zebras and the number of lions.

Let $\text{net}$ be the convex hull of the lions.

Let $C_\text{net}$ be the largest origin-centred circle that is contained within this convex hull. This may not exist, in which case we consider it to be of radius 0.

Let $C_\text{zebra}$ be the minimal origin-centred bounding circle for some subset $Z$ of the zebras.

[image: Zebra Net]

**Claim:**

The lions can force $\text{radius}(C_\text{net}) > k \cdot \text{radius}(C_\text{zebra})$ for some $k > 10$ and a nonzero subset $Z$ regardless of the zebras' strategy and initial placement.

As $n$ is increased, you can have an arbitrary number of zebras inside $C_\text{zebra}$ with an arbitrary number of lions on the perimeter of $\text{net}$ and $k$ can be arbitrarily increased.

**Proof:**

Without loss of generality, assume the lions go first.

Consider a circle centred on the origin containing all of the initial positions of the zebras and lions. Let its radius be $\delta$ and let $\omega \gg \delta$ and $\omega \gg 100$.

Have some small subset of lions of cardinality at least $l \ge 3$ move to equidistributed points at radius $\omega$.

We select some small number $z$ of zebras and examine the maximum radius of $C_\text{zebra}$ which doesn't contain $z$ zebras. This is obviously the maximum radius of the $z$th-smallest distance from the origin to each zebra.

Evidently, this is maximized by having $z - 1$ zebras not move and having $n - z + 1$ zebras move an equal distance from an initial offset of $\delta$. There are rounding errors since the distance might not be a multiple of 100, but since $\omega \gg 100$ this is unimportant.

Thus we have that the radius is at best $\frac{l \cdot (\omega + 2\delta + 100)}{n - z + 1} + \delta + 100$ where $l \cdot (\omega + 2\delta + 100)$ is approximately the distance moved by the zebras in the time it took the lions to get into place. This approximates to $\frac{l \cdot \omega}{n - z + 1} + \delta$.

The radius of $C_\text{net}$ relative to $\omega$ is worst in the case of a triangle, in which case it is $\omega / 2$.

This means that $k$ is at worst

$$
\frac{\text{radius}(C_\text{net})}{\text{radius}(C_\text{zebra})} \approx
\frac{\omega / 2}{\frac{l \cdot \omega}{n - z + 1} + \delta}
$$

For $n = 100$, $z = 3$, $l = 3$, we have

$$
\frac{\omega}{\frac{3}{49} \omega + 2 \delta} \approx \frac{\omega}{\frac{3}{49} \omega} \approx 15
$$

Obviously as $n$ increases, the fraction $\frac{l \cdot \omega}{n - z + 1}$ will decrease. By increasing $\omega$ in terms of $\delta$ you can thus make this arbitrarily large even for arbitrary $l$ and $z$. A rigorous proof is up to the reader.

---

So "trapping" a zebra is easy... what matters is if you can do anything with that knowledge.

Comment: Totally agree with your assessment. I would put it in different term. A single lion can move "100 faster" than the zebra 100 pack. The challenge is not if, but as you concluded - how?

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. A lot of the answers are not of any use, yours is helpful.

Comment: @Veedrac Can you tighten the net? Two avenues seem promising: (1) average speed of lions vs zebras if there are more zebras inside than lions on the perimeter; and (2) sum of time taken for all lions to travel directly to some point (or some zebra?) in the net compared with sum of time taken for all zebras to escape the original or shrinking perimeter.

Comment: @Veedrac Where do you define $\omega$?

Comment: @Lawrence "and let $\omega \gg \delta$ and $\omega \gg 100$". It's just an arbitrary large constant if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that line, but was wondering whether you had in mind some other semantics for $\omega$.

Answer (score 7):

My final assumption is

> zebras can win

following this strategy :

The zebras choose to be uniformly distributed on a circle, distanced sufficiently from lions' center of gravity - which the circle is the centered on.

They will not be doomed to lose the game given:

> - Any zebra is instructed to escape by following the vector in the direction parallel to $\sum \vec{l_i b}+\vec{z_i b}$ where $l_i$ are the lions' coordinates, $z_{i}$ are the closest other zebras' coordinates and $b$ is the zebra itself.
> - When any zebra feels a lion being closest to it, it should take turn to move.
>     In technical terms, this is when it has the smallest $d = \min ||\vec{l_i b}||$.

This solution can prevent

- any zebra to be stranded by two lions both sides or
- any zebra to be amassed in same spot with another zebra

because the unique condition where any zebra is condemned to death is that

$$
\sum (\vec{lb} + \vec{zb}) = \vec{0}
$$

or that a single $\vec{zb} = \vec{0}$ or $\vec{lb} = \vec{0}$.

The solution is illustrated here:

[image: Lions and zebras with vectors between them.]

[This little simulation](http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m794961) can clarify my proposition for two zebras and two lions.

---

**This part is a reply for @Veedrac**

Considering 6 zebras and 6 lions, I could implement this simulation in which by I might not surround any zebra since the zebras are fleeing the lions' center of gravity. I made this simulation open-source to unconvict myself from any cheating.

[Here is a simulation for 6 zebras and 6 lions.](http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m804603)

> **Note:** Try to move the cursor slowly centimeter by centimeter because there is some kind of weird bug in that code. I couldn't handle it due to my inexperience with this type of scripting language.

Secondly, I don't really believe that Veedrac's theory is really fruitful because zebras are always escaping any kind of fencing that lions try to impose.

Lets assume $k$ lions succeeded in surrounding one lion.

Let $r$ be the radius of that circle and $2 \pi r$ is the perimeter.

Any successful encirclement is when the length of each arc between two lions is gradually shrinked until it is no more than 100m with a zebra still inside the circle.

When $k$ lions made a unitary $u = 100\text{m}$ step, the zebra would have made $ku$ steps.

When a zebra is doomed to be caught, the radius equals $\frac{(k-1)}{k} r$,  the perimeter of the circle is $2 \pi \frac{(k-1)r}{k}$ and the length of each arc is $\frac{2 \pi \frac{(k-1)r}{k}}{k}$

The condition where a zebra is caught is $\frac{2 \pi \frac{(k-1)r}{k}}{k} \leq u = 1$ and the maximal length of the circle's radius is $\frac {k^2}{2\pi(k-1)}$.

When there are $k = 100$ lions, $r \approx 16u=1600\text{m}$, which can be avoided when we consider an enough large difference between the zebras' and lions' accumulation center before the game starts.

Comment: But the lion in the second column could chase his zebra for a number of moves, until he is significantly below the zebra in column 4. If the zebras then stick to their strategy, and assume that the one closest to a zebra moves first, then the lion from col 2 could then move across into col 4 and turn around and it would then be really easy. The  additional lions break this solution for the zebras and it actually becomes one of the easiest for the lion. They could last a while moving side to side but this would allow the lions to move alternately and trap the zebra.

Comment: @Ryan Durrant thx for noticing it , iv changed the content

Comment: "this solution can prevent any zebra to be stranded by two lions both sides" → What exactly do you mean by this? It is provably possible for three lions to form a triangle with which a single zebra is contained.

Comment: @Veedrac maybe they can have a zebra between but not sufficiently near to be caught.

Comment: @Abidare001 I don't really get your proof. What invariant are you using to show this? Using your simulation and treating one of the zebras as a lion (since each zebra doesn't distinguish between who is where) I am able to capture the other zebra if it is surrounded by a triangle. It seems this would disprove your claim, but I don't get the claim well enough to say.

Comment: well of course u would be able to catch a zebra when you position it few steps from a lions claws , i have said before zebras must be divergent enough

Comment: @Abidare001 This property seems to be invariant of distance; if the zebra is centred inside a triangle then it gets caught. It would help if you gave a version with three lions.

Comment: @Veedrac im already trying , thanks for encouragement , but i think this condition leads to advantageous results since zebras are randomly placed that helps the escaping vector V to be continuously variant and not nil

Comment: is it clearer now?

Comment: @Agawa001 What is a rayon? Do you mean radius?

Comment: @Agawa001 "When a zebra is doomed to be caught , rayon equals $\frac{(k-1)}{k}r$" → Why?

Comment: @Agawa001 Also, I don't think you can assume that the lions all move uniformly inwards. They might do better if they some make more specific moves. Also, the strategy may be heavily dependent on trapping more than one zebra.

Comment: yes @Veedrac its hard to interpret lions behavior when they perform stochastic moves , but i have considered consistent demarche toward that zebra . it would be too hard when lions act slyly

Comment: I don't think I agree your conclusion is particularly strong, but the simulation is definitely helpful!

Comment: As i have said before a sucessfull encirlement is when the group of lions form a radius=16 u circle arround a zebra which i couldnt do using my simulation cuz zebra is always avoiding lion's center of gathering

Comment: but i cant hide many flaws which my code could contain , like immediacy of reaction . such reaction is a fruit of many variants including the narrowest and largest gap between two lions , distance and position of each lion . this is what is called heuristics in artificial intelligence and game theory

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically on an infinite plane the zebras can be set up so that the lions are unable to reach them. For a start they could start lightyears away and then continue to move away.

There might be certain situations in which the lions can win, for examlpe if the zebras were placed randomly in non-optimal positions then one would almost certainly get caught. But if the zebras are placed in well thought out locations, then regardless of the lions location no one lion can ever catch a zebra, it would just continue to move away.

One way a lion might attempt to beat this, would be to imagine that the zebras set up to surround the lions, meaning they can not get trapped, if a lion were to chase one zebra until the lion itself was outside of the zebras, it could then turn around and push a zebra back towards the other lions this could work as only one zebra can move to avoid the lion. If we assume that the closest zebra moves then the lion simply has to ensure it stays closer to the first zebra until it is outside of the circle/line/square the zebras are attempting to surround the lions with. This doesn't have to be a regular shape, and they could be more or less randomly spread out, but as soon as the lion gets to the other side, by maintaining a small distance it will eventually get a fair way past. It can then turn around. until the distance between it and the first zebra exceeds that of any other zebra and the nearest lion.

The first lion (A) would have to be selected such that another zebra (X) is nearby but farther from the next lion (B) than most of the other zebras are from their respective lions.

When Lion A then turns back, another zebra (Y) will move as he will be closest to a lion. This has to be chosen such that X is not the next closest to a lion.

The same strategy can then be used by other lions to circle the zebra X, by chasing another Zebra Z they can position them selves around zebra X who doesn't get a chance to move until surrounded. They can then close in. The lions can move in any direction, and if we assume that the zebras move to the farthest point from the lion, this allows them to push them around. More than one lion can move to push around the same zebra, and since they can also force other zebras to move by getting closer to them, they will eventually be able to surround a zebra.

Comment: Veedrac's answer might help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm believe the zebra's can always win as before. The main reason being that the plain is infinite, and that the zebra's place themselves second. How they do this is simply the same was as in the previous question. Each zebra makes its on strip in which if there was only 1 lion, they would all be safe. the issue is that there is 100 lions, but this doesn't matter. Since any number of points (less than infinite) can be scaled down to a single point given infinite space.

So once all the lions have placed themselves, the zebra's need to be places such that they 100 lions can be considered to be a single point below all of the zebra's strips. Although this might not seem physically possible (since we are dealing with limits with infinity), in the world of math it could be resolved to a solution. Unfortunately my math hat doesn't seem to be around so I can't provide the proper proof to this concept. (Hopefully someone else would be able to verify this to possibly conclude this problem)

As a side note. You stated that:

> Note that once a zebra gets encircled by the lions, he is bound to
>   lose. So the aim for the lions could be to create a wide ring around a
>   single zebra.

But you did not provide any proof to this. I believe this can be throwing some people off as they could be going down a false path, unless this is a rule that you are creating as another win situation.

Comment: +1 for the statement by OP without proof. Although the strip method won't work, even with two lions. The lion can all go to one strip, then one goes upward till the horizontal distance to the vertical line in which the zebra on the strip to the right of current strip is half the vertical distance to the zebra on the strip to the right. Then another lion goes downward until the zebra to the right is between the two lions. Then both lions go to the vertical line the zebra to the right is in. Both lions will reach the line before the zebra to the right can escape. Then it can be captured easily.

Comment: @justhalf I didn't specify how wide a ring, or how many lions are required. I myself don't know.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: Then I think it's better to remove that hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The zebras are bound to win!

**REASON**

> As the lions place themselves first and the grid is infinite the zebra's can place  themselves at a distance greater than 1 km (1 km is exaggerated, any distance =< than 200m will do) from the closest lion and make sure that they are not in between any lions.

**EXAMPLE 1**

> Let there be 1 zebra and 1 lion.
>
> In such a case the zebra will place itself at a distance of =< 200m
>   ; and will always manage to get away
>
> **Conclusion:** Zebra wins

**EXAMPLE 2**

> Let there be two lions and two zebras
>
> In such a case after the lions have placed themselves, the zebras will place themselves in such a manner so that they are NOT in between two lions and the minimum distance from both lions is 200m
>
> The lion may come closer to the zebras and separte them, however it will need the support of the 2nd lion to surround it, and in the time the 2nd lion will come for support, the 2nd zebra will get away
>
> **Conclusion:** Zebras win

***SIMILARLY EVEN IF THERE ARE 100 LIONS AND 100 ZEBRAS, THE ZEBRAS WILL USE THE SAME EXACT STRATEGY, AND HENCE MANAGE TO WIN EACH AND EVERY TIME***

*Until and unless the grid is finite and the number of lions and zebras is tweaked, the solution won't change.*

Comment: I don't see how your strategy generalizes even for three zebras. For example, why can't one lion chase one zebra until the lion is on a line with two other zebras, and then chase the closer of the two zebras until it reaches the other zebra, when the two zebras cannot escape from the one lion, as they move more slowly together.

Comment: Initially the zebra will not be in the same horizontal strip as any lion.Whenever a lion enters the vertical strip in which the zebra is present then the zebra will flee vertically. And if the lion chooses the 2nd zebra then it will further have to move horizontally till it reaches a point so that the zebra is in the same vertical strip as itself, here again the zebra will flee vertically if the lion chooses to chase it.

Comment: What strips are you referring to? Do you mean the strategy used in the answer to the original question?

Comment: Yes, its basically the same strategy!

Comment: @TheDragonista Having the zebras locked to a horiontal line  will not work, even for 2 lions and zebras.  Have lion 1 chase zebra 1 in zebra 1's strip for one turn.  Then have lion 2 chase zebra 2 for significantly longer than the distance between zebra 1's line and zebra 2's line.  At this point lion2 can enter zebra 1's strip and cause zebra 1 to be sandwitched between the two lions.

Comment: @Dragonista Your examples are not relevant since the number involved is critical. You are missing the key point: One movement of a lion closes the range to more than one Zebra. On its face it seems that by creating a chase team of lion you could circle a zebra and force it into a trap. The challenge how this is achieved.

Comment: This was my initial reaction: The lions are placed first, the zebras automatically win because they can be placed light years away from the lions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the lions can win on an infinite plane.  First, draw a circle around the lions, the smallest one needed to encircle all the lions.  Now, draw another circle whose radius is 10^r light years, where r is the radius of the lion circle in meters.  Put the zebras equidistantly on this outer circle.

Whichever zebra is nearest the moving lion moves directly outwards.

I can't see a strategy that the lions could use to overtake the zebras.  Suppose one lion goes after one zebra.  The zebra moves outwards in response.  Suppose the lion goes after that zebra until he hits the zebra's starting point.  Then do same with another lion, going after a zebra two zebras away from the first one.  Then can you perhaps trap the zebra in the middle?  Seems to me that the middle zebra would at some point become the closest and start to move away.

Comment: To make things easier to visualise, I'll just talk about 12 zebras on a clockface. So a lion in the centre of this circle heads to the zebra at the 12 o'clock position. It keeps heading that way for, say, 3 times the radius (R) of that initial zebra circle. At that point it starts heading in a 3 o'clock direction, the 12 o'clock zebra is still the closest so continues to move in a 12 o'clock direction. After the lion has moved a decent distance the 12 zebra is no longer the closest, and instead the 1 o'clock zebra moves. But moving 'outwards' means it is heading towards that moving lion.

Comment: If you've gotten to three times the radius of the circle, you've passed a point where another zebra is closer, in which case it would have moved instead of the original one.  Not so?

Comment: No, the Zebra that the lion started chasing will be the closest until the lion stops chasing it.

Comment: @Taemyr For 100 zebras, Mashton's strategy works well, since the angle between any 2 zebras is only $3.6^{\circ}$.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I was replying to BobRodes.  Mashton's strategy fails for 4 zebras, I think it suceeds for any number greater than this.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here - this is only one lion, but your zebra strategy is the same, so the zebra could be caught. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9036/the-lion-and-the-zebras/9323#9323

Answer (score 0):

The lions will win.

Because:

> Assuming the zebras take their optimal strategy, which would be to create a circle an arbitrary distance out from the center of the lions. Let's say that the zebras make such a large circle that any distance a lion is from the center is negligible, so we can say they are all at the direct center of the circle. This will look like this:[image]
>  with the lions at the red dot in the center (assume its a point, as explained above) and the zebras around the circle.

When they move:

> A single lion moves directly north, going for the zebra at that spot on the circle (let's call it zebra A). That zebra would in turn move away, and the lion would keep moving in that direction. At some point, the lion would be closer to one of the adjacent zebras to the one it is following (let's call them B and C), however it would keep moving in a straight line toward the original zebra. To keep safe, all three of those zebras would have to move out in their respective path. For this lion strategy, the lion would keep moving in the straight line following zebra A, so B and C could stay in the same spot, but that doesn't matter. Either way, the lion would get far enough outside the original circle (if B and C don't move) or the arc that B and C make (if they move in their respective paths) that it would either catch up to A or get to a point where it can get to a point that is in between B/C and the center of the circle.  If it catches up to A then the lions would obviously win. If it gets to a point that is on the opposite side of B/C and the center of the circle (all the other lions), then it would have that zebra trapped. So the lions win. Here are a couple pictures to explain:[image][image]
> The only other thing that the zebras could do is have B and C each move out of their path (the straight path from the center of the circle). If this were to happen, they would eventually get in the way of the zebra that is on that side of them. In this case the lion could just go straight toward those zebras, and having both zebras in a (relatively) close location, they would be trapped because the lion could move faster (only one lion and two zebras escaping, so lion moves 100m and then each zebra must move 100, so lion moves 200 for each 100 per zebra).

EDIT:

> I guess a better way to word this would be that the single lion goes toward the center zebra of 3 that are closest together, angle-wise. No matter how the zebras are set up, at least 3 zebras must be adjacent and separated by angles of 3.6 degrees or less. One zebra could be on the opposite side of the lions from the other zebras, in which case the lion would go for a zebra that has the least sum of angles between itself and the two adjacent zebras. If the zebras were separated by 3.6 degrees each, then this would be the optimal strategy for them, however they would still lose. They wouldn't lose if this angle is greater than or equal to 90 degrees, because no matter how far out the lion goes, it's distance to cut off any zebra will always be longer than the distance the zebra must go to get to that same point, so it will never catch any of the zebras.  For any angle less than 90 degrees between each zebra, the lion can get to a point far enough away from the circle that it will be able to "cut off" one of the adjacent zebras to the one it was following. If the adjacent zebra that the lion targets decides to cut over, it will be cutting into the path of another one of the zebras, and if two of these zebras are in the same path, then it will be simple for a lion to get one of them because the lion can move 200m for each 100m moved by each zebra.

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure your logic is right, but maybe it is. Second, the zebras are allowed to place themselves *after* the lions have done so. If a circular formation does not work, they might have a better way to position themselves.

Comment: Okay I sort of reworded it to address that.

Comment: I think you need to go into more detail about how to finish off the zebras once a they are between the moving lion and the other lions.  Merely saying the zebras are "trapped" doesn't seem sufficient.  Is there some state from which you could show a concrete winning strategy for the lions that would catch a zebra in a computable amount of time?

Comment: It seems like the lions should be able to win, but I can't figure out a strategy for them to actually do so.  It would seem like a zebra that has to escape toward other zebras or lions would be in a losing situation, but I can't figure out any metric which would decrease at a rate sufficient to show that it would reach a winning value in finite time (rather than asymptotically approaching some non-winning value).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a single zebra is caught in an infinitely large "circle" of L lions, which move just on the sides of this shape. This might not be the optimal lion position and movement, but it is reasonable enough to start with I believe.

For 6 it can be shown that simply approaching any lion will require neighboring lion to approach that lion to fix the hole. Obviously this cannot work, the other hole on the other side of lion being approached remains.

For 12, they can fix the hole but 2 lions approaching that one will make 2 other holes where zebra can escape. Get halfway to that lion and then run through the hole.
The same happens from 24 on, except in 2 steps - halfway to that lion, then halfway to the other lion, then escape through another hole... The more lions you add, the less lions can and need to move, but you still keep making holes for zebra's escape.
You can continue for many more lions with the same conclusion - lions are too sparse to catch the zebra. In fact you would require infinitely many lions. Think electrons on surface shading that one inside as to how they should move.

Can lions move more optimal? With infinite distance, nope. If that lion that is being approached moves towards the zebra, or anything else, hole will be just bigger and make escape easier.
Sure, with finite distances they could perhaps catch the zebra in the circle, but this isn't relevant in this case - zebras can start infinitely apart from each other, so lions will have to be "more infinitely" from the zebras to trap them.

So, if zebras are to be eaten, you need to trap more than one.

Now there are 2 open questions:

With how many lions can you surround how many zebras?

If you trap Z infinitely spaced zebras, can you force them together to finite distances? If you cannot, there will be obviously no meal for lions.
Assuming you can, the problem translates to the one of single zebra that is 1/Z speed of L lions in best case for lions. And when/if any zebra gets out of the circle, the remaining ones get faster.

2 zebras have the obvious strategy of "we separate, one gets out first, now there is a single zebra with lions still far enough".
For 3 zebras, I think 12-ish lions should work, but this is just a guess.

Comment: It's not possible to trap infinitely spaced zebras in finite time, but for any arbitrary spacing of zebras it will possible in finite time for a group of L lions to form a circle around a concentric circle containing group of 50 zebras, such that the ratio of the diameters will be 50/L.  So if one were to try to have eight lions surround zebras, then no matter how far apart the zebras start, the lions could reach a state where they were equally spaced around a circle, and the distance between any of 50 zebras and the nearest lion was greater than the distance between lions.

Comment: What I can't figure out is how to define an invariant such that once such a state is reached, the zebras will be closer to capture after each move than they were before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question wording gives wiggle room for interpretation and that in turn affects the answer, or at least the proof involved. 
I could take the wording to mean each animal has to take a turn, lion then zebra, and each one is numbered 1 through 100 with lion 1 going first then zebra 1 then lion 2 zebra 2 so on and so forth, and we assume that these lions and zebras can communicate instantly across vast distances (entangled perhaps?) and also at any one time know where all the other animals were then the lions could pick one zebra to take out and work together to do this, as that particular zebra would only be able to move once every 200 turns meaning eventually it gets yammed.

If however any lion or zebra can have a their team's turn, they cannot communicate with each other and they don't know where the other animals are, whilst being on an infinite plain, I would think you would need to invoke chaos theory (of which the mathematics is slightly beyond me). Even though the movement of the animals could be described as systematic, on that scale and without knowledge of the position or behaviour of the other players each one would essentially be behaving randomly. If we continue on this track of thought we would undoubtedly encounter the uncertainty principle hence we can't actually determine the initial situation of the system (it being complex) and so we cannot accurately predict it's evolution.

I would argue that if any starting situation and turn structure you can think of was done over infinite time with infinite iterations, that eventually a zebra would be caught as I would expect every different outcome to be a possibility, like in the Mark Steel lecture where he runs at the wall a bazillion times and eventually pops through it 'coz quantum'.

Comment: So basically the essence of your answer is 'I don't really know'? Your second interpretation is the correct one, and I really don't think we have to specify every single kink in the question.

Comment: My interpretation is that no one really knows

Comment: Well, that's what the question's about! To see whether someone can find a good solution.

Comment: @Scarabanja The lions are not numbered, 'turn' just means which team's turn it is, and the team can move the same animal multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

The lions can eventually win.

Let's take a kind of bad starting position for the lions: they are in a line, the zebras are in a line perpendicular to the lions, but 1km from one of the ends (capital T, top bar is zebras, lions are upright bar, and a space between).

Let's say then the lions move into an upward parabola. Well, the zebras are gonna be quite a bit further out. Even then, the ends of the lion parabola can move upward enough that eventually they will be higher than some zebras. Repeat to get move lions above some zebras. Eventually, you will be able to box a zebra in.

Comment: If the lions are quite apart, the zebras could pass through the parabola wall. If the wall is tight (and small), the zebras can go round it. As the zebras place themselves later, they could start with a scattered position.

Comment: I am not sure this is the right strategy but it is clearly based on a good assumption: When one lion is moving there is a challenge to decide which zebra to move, since the distance is closed to more than one zebra.

Answer (score -2):

[image: cirhex]

Let's draw the circumference of a circle with R1=100 m. And let's construct inside the circle a hexagon with side a=R1. Let's assume all the lions' front parts (noses, toes or whatever) do not extend beyond the circumference and are place equidistantly from each other around the perimeter. Let's put the zebras inside the hexagon, such that no part of their fronts are closer than a quarter of a meter from the perimeter of the circle. If a zebra tries to escape and does not succeed and gets eaten by a lion then the radius decreases by 10 m, eg. R1=100, R2=90, R3=80, etc. If a zebra escapes and saves itself, then the radius increases exponentially, eg. R1=10^2, R2=10^3, R3=10^4, etc. In the new circles and hexagons, the same conditions exist as for the first circle with the hexagon inside it. If two zebras escape unharmed, then all zebras are going to escape. On the other hand, if two zebras are eaten by the lions, then all zebras are doomed.

Comment: @ghosts in the code.  Is this not the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @ghosts in the code. I am still waiting for your response.

Comment: I do not see how this is an answer to the question. If the lion team has a turn and any lion is within 100m of any zebra then the lions win. If they can never achieve this, then they lose.

Comment: The distance between the lions at the circle perimeter is about 5 meters because the lions are placed equidistantly. The best spot for a zebra to escape is at a vertex of the hexagon. The lions cannot cross into the hexagon. The lion starts to run when the zebra has crossed the perimeter. If the zebra runs faster than the lion then it will escape. If the lion runs faster, then the zebra will be killed. The outcome has 50% chance of success for each of them. The first outcome is very critical. As you can see from the numbers on the second escape the zebra has more than 90% chance of surviving.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is still not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. If a zebra is eaten, the game ends. Also there will be no likely be no concept of probability, since it's a turn-wise deterministic game. Also a single lion chasing a single zebra at equal speed means the zebra escapes with 100% probability.